# Short black flashs when switching fragments in navigation drawer

Tags: android, flash, android-fragments, navigation

It's 7am and i've been searching all night long on this.
I got a Nav drawer and list which dynamically adds fragments to Main activity and switchs to the clicked fragment.

I'm new so let me try be explaing what i tried:

1. When i first started this project it was fine, now i have black flashs whenever i switch and i can't find any reasons.
   I thought it was "heavy" work in the onCreate of the fragments, but other than loading views and setting their texts/images there isn't much more work, other than 1 fragment which contains a timer i got 4 others who do nothing but present data.
2. 1 of the fragments is completely empty in code, and it also flashs.
3. i had animation in the transaction, but it used to work, not anymore, flashs. i tried removing it but i still get the flashs.
4. I've read about SurfaceView but it seems too complicated for my project which is just a simple time&money tracker.

important notes: 
when i click the Back button there's no flash and the animation runs smoothly.
I'm testing on my own device which is Galaxy s5.

What i've read so far that didn't help:
[Whole screen turns into black for a short while when first switching between Fragment and MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386881/whole-screen-turns-into-black-for-a-short-while-when-first-switching-between-fra)

[Starting activity shows black flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310594/starting-activity-shows-black-flash)

[Switching between Android Navigation Drawer image and Up caret when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258020/switching-between-android-navigation-drawer-image-and-up-caret-when-using-fragme)

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639

**

- EDIT

**
I think i have a lead:
The flickering could be caused by the closeDrawer i have called right after i commit a new fragment.
when the drawer is open, the ui behind it is dimmed, i disabled that close call and when i change fragments no flickering.

i don't know how to fix it tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After last edit i got a better description of the problem and found a good solution(at least for me)
link:
[DrawerLayout's item click - When is the right time to replace fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491557/drawerlayouts-item-click-when-is-the-right-time-to-replace-fragment)

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switchFragments(position); // your fragment transactions go here
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

}